# How to show popup window in "-ing" event receiver?

Tags: javascript

I created event receiver that uses web service, and I want to show the result on popup window.

I know we can use different kinds of redirect in synchronous receivers, but it is called by checkbox in filtered datasheet view, so I'm not able to make redirect back to my page.

So I need to show some popup window. I know we can get HttpContext object in constructor of event receiver, but now I don't know how to call javascript window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event Receivers are not UI related. You cannot open popups from them.
Also do not be sure of getting HttpContext in event receiver code.
Events can be fired by many agents other than user action in browser, e.g. if event is fired as a result of an action by by timer job or console application or workflow, HttpContext will be null so it is absolutely not good design to have redirection logic in event receiver.

Comment: justforkix09, thank You for Your answer! Yes I know that work with HttpContext from event receiver is a bad hack, but in my case I understand the risks and in my case is more important to show this message :(

Comment: I tried out your scenario, used Response.Write to add javascript to the page. It executes fine on list view but does not work on datasheet view. Asynchronous functionality of the data sheet object doesn't let the additional script tag come on to the page

Comment: justforkix09Gm, thank You for answer! Can You show Your code-snippet? I tried this(kink below) to show the window and it does nothing(no exceptions but no work too), in datasheet and form views no matter
http://madskristensen.net/post/JavaScript-AlertShow(e2809dmessagee2809d)-from-ASPNET-code-behind.aspx

Comment: That's my variant:
[code] public HttpContext context;
        public Page page;
        public MyReceiver()
        {
            context = HttpContext.Current;
            page = context.CurrentHandler as Page;
        }
// and then I tried to show like this:
Alert.Show(page, "A");
[/code]

Comment: I checked that link and my guess is [HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page] will be null as event is not being handled by page handler. As there is a null check ahead, you are not getting any exception.  As for my code, I did not bother with registering the script , just wrote [Context.Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('This message is from event handler');</script>");] and this worked for normal list/forms view.(Context is the HttpContext object stored by the constructor)

Comment: Yes this trick will only work in form views.

But for datasheet views I resolved my task on the other side - writing result message in Afterproperties, in "Log" field instead of javascript window. And datasheet view updates in online mode, no need refresh the page.

Sorry for my bad english :)

justforkix09, thank You very much for Your responses! :)

Best regards,Gennady